# calling nodejs function from the same file and from the different file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Model.js file has the following entry

```
exports.update = function(tag,view,date){
{
    .....
    ....
}
```

and calling the function like

```
 update('test','1213','11/10/2014')
```

it throws the following error,

```
update('test','1213','11/10/2014')
^
ReferenceError: update is not defined
```

I can call the update module from the different file, without any error something like this

```
var model =  require('./Model');
model.update('test','1213','2001/1/23')
```

The question is how can invoke the Update method from the same js (Model.js )file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In model.js

```
exports.update = function update(tag, view, date) { ... }
exports.update('red', 'colors', new Date())
```

Also consider declaring a local variable if you call the method often (like in a loop)

```
var update = exports.update = function update(tag, view, date) { ... }
update('red', 'colors', new Date())
```

Inside foo.js

```
var update = require('./model').update
update('yellow', 'colors', new Date())
```

Is not clear from the question itself what the update method does and on which data, so the answer may be tweaked if you provide real code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to first define the function, and then export the function like this-

```js
var update=function(tag,view,date){
......
}

module.exports={
  update:update
}
```

By doing this you can access the 'update()' function from inside as well as outside of the file.

Comment: This is also a good practice, to have a specific section of your file dedicated to what you are exporting.